# How to get SimpleXml attributes in PHP

Tags: php, attributes, simplexml

I need to parse this [ECB currencies](https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml) rates. But as I try to access the attributes I get an empty values. The code Looks like

```
$xml = new \SimpleXMLElement($xml);

/** @var \SimpleXMLElement $c */
foreach ($xml->Cube->Cube->Cube as $c)
{
    Debugger::log($c->attributes()->currency);  // OK
    Debugger::log($c->attributes()['currency']);  // OK
    Debugger::log('*************************');
    $this->currency->setCurrencyRate($c->attributes()->currency, $c->attributes()->rate);
}


public function setCurrencyRate($currency, $rate)
{
    $data = [
        'currency' => $currency,  // ERROR empty string
        'rate' => $rate,  // ERROR empty string
        'updated' => new \DateTime(),
    ];
    $this->db->query('INSERT INTO currencies_rates ', $data, ' ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE currency = ', $currency, ' rate = ', $rate, 'updated = ', new \DateTime());
}
```

Here is the xml

```
<gesmes:Envelope xmlns:gesmes="http://www.gesmes.org/xml/2002-08-01" xmlns="http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref">
    <gesmes:subject>Reference rates</gesmes:subject>
    <gesmes:Sender>
        <gesmes:name>European Central Bank</gesmes:name>
    </gesmes:Sender>
    <Cube>
        <Cube time="2021-12-13">
            <Cube currency="USD" rate="1.1278"/>
            <Cube currency="JPY" rate="128.19"/>
            <Cube currency="BGN" rate="1.9558"/>
            <Cube currency="CZK" rate="25.401"/>
            <Cube currency="DKK" rate="7.4362"/>
            <Cube currency="GBP" rate="0.85158"/>
            <Cube currency="HUF" rate="367.07"/>
            ...
        </Cube>
    </Cube>
</gesmes:Envelope>
```

I dont understand it.

Comment: Try explicitly casting to a string - either `$this->currency->setCurrencyRate( (string) $c->attributes()->currency, (string) $c->attributes()->rate);`, or within the method, `'currency' => (string) $currency, 'rate' => (string) $rate,`

Comment: Please can you [edit] to include a sample of the XML you're parsing, so we don't have to download a copy from an external website?

Comment: Thanks a lot. Why is it so? It is really not user friendly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SimpleXML, pretty much everything returns a `SimpleXMLElement` object that you can carry on interacting with. There isn't a lot you can do with an attribute object, but you can for instance write this:

```
$currencyAttribute = $c->attributes()->currency;
echo $currencyAttribute->getName(); // 'currency'
```

In order to get the *text content* of an element or attribute, you have to *cast it to string*. A lot of the time, you don't notice this, because it happens automatically when you pass the object to `echo`, concatenate it like `'Currency: . $currencyAttribute`, interpolate it like `"Currency: $currencyAttribute"`, etc. But sometimes you need to *force* it to be a string before passing it somewhere, using the `(string)` syntax (or `strval()` function):

```
$this->currency->setCurrencyRate( (string) $c->attributes()->currency, (string) $c->attributes()->rate);
```